# Check if the username already exists with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, mysqli

I try to check if the username and email from input fields already exists in my database before to create a new user.

this is login.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
$pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$pseudo=mysql_real_escape_string($pseudo);
$pseudo=ltrim($pseudo);
$pseudo=rtrim($pseudo);

$mail=mysql_real_escape_string($mail);
$mail=trim($mail);

$sql=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bdd_name');
$query=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_people WHERE 'PEO_PSEUDO'='".$pseudo."' OR 'PEO_MAIL'='".$mail."'");
$result = mysqli_prepare($sql,$query);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($result);

if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo 1;
 }
 else {
 echo 2;
 }
mysqli_stmt_free_result($result);
mysqli_stmt_close($result);
?>
```

And this is a part of my JavaScript :

```
var pseudo=$("#pseudo").val();
var mail=$("#mail").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: {pseudo:pseudo, mail:mail}
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (result==1) {
                good();
            }
            else if (result==2) {
                bad();
            }
        });
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

I'm on this since hours now and I'm clueless...

Comment: That's the wrong way of using prepared statements. And if you really want to use this syntax, use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. And do you see an error message?

Comment: When I try mysqli_real_escape_string it keeps loading. I don't know why. And I don't know how to display error message, I'm very noob actually.

Comment: Use it *after* you open a connection, but again, use prepared statements the correct way, like redreggae described in his answer. Show error messages using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: Thank you I will read about the error functions in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things going wrong.
Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` cause you're working with `mysqli_*`. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead. But better use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` because you're working with prepared statements. And if you work with `COUNT(*)` you always get 1 row.

```
$pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM t_people WHERE PEO_PSEUDO = ? OR PEO_MAIL = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $pseudo, $mail);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$numRows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

With `COUNT(*)` (which is more efficient) it goes like:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as numrows FROM t_people WHERE PEO_PSEUDO = ? OR PEO_MAIL = ?";
...
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $numRows);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// work with $numRows
```

Comment: Woaw, it's working now.

Thank you  :

    $sql=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bdd_name');
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as numrows FROM t_people WHERE PEO_PSEUDO = ? OR PEO_MAIL = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $pseudo, $mail);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $numRows);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    
    echo $numRows;
    
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong operator for escaping use backtick operator in your query like this

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_people WHERE `PEO_PSEUDO`='".$pseudo."' OR `PEO_MAIL`='".$mail."'"
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that but the result is still the same after.

Comment: -1 for counter effective approach. He wants to know if email or login is already used, not how many occurences of email/login is in DB, therefore not using `LIMIT 1` is just a waste, as it is sufficient to know if there's `0` or `non 0` rows matching given criteria.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I've added the `LIMIT 1` to my answer below. But with `COUNT(*)` there's always 1 row?!

Comment: @regreggae yes, theoretically you are correct. it should be always 0 or 1 row, but without `LIMIT` db will not stop after finding 1st row. And that's my point here.

Comment: Thank you. I have just added the limit 1.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think you're wrong. `LIMIT` doesn't make any difference on `COUNT(*)`. Only if you use `LIMIT 0` then you get no result. Read [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50005)